# What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 100?

Tags: java, biginteger, lcm

Following is my code where I tried to calculate LCM of all numbers from one to hundred by using BigInteger inn Java. But it does not provide any ans.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CommonOneToHundred {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BigInteger res =new BigInteger("1");
        int i = 2;
        while(i<=100){
        res = lcm(res,BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        i++;
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
       static BigInteger lcm(BigInteger x, BigInteger y)
        {
            BigInteger a;
            //a = (x > y) ? x : y; // a is greater number
            a = y;
            while(true)
            {
                if(a.divide(x).equals(0) &&  a.divide(y).equals(0))
                    return a;
                a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            }   
        }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not take multiplication of highest power's of all primes till 100. Here is my code in python.

```
primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
ans = 1
for prime in primes:
  power = 0
  tmp = 1
  while tmp <= 100:
    tmp = tmp*prime
    power += 1
  ans = ans * prime**(power-1)

print ans
```

The answer is `69720375229712477164533808935312303556800`.

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: @kulst I added the code. Do comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Nope, I can confirm that it is the correct result.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Sure even I was doubtful that I made a mistake. Had to check again :D

Comment: The trick is that your answer @Nikolas forgot to take into account the highest power of the prime, less than 100. The right power can actually be calculated: `log(100) / log(prime)`, no need to loop.

Comment: @sasha the ans is ryt.

Answer (score 0):

Using LCM accumulatively from 1 to 100 is going to take extremely long time, even if it does not overflow the `BigInteger` data type. Try a different algorithm. First prepare a prime table 2,3,5,7,...,97, then prime factorize every number from 1 to 100 and find the highest power of every prime in all 100 numbers. Finally, multiply those powers of prime factors using probably the `BigInteger` type. The answer is 2^6 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 7^2 * all primes from 11 to 97 = `69720375229712477164533808935312303556800`. In fact, the prime factorization step can be saved. One can just find the highest power of each prime that is within 100 instead. The `BigInteger` multiplication cannot be avoided, since the number exceeds `long long`.

Comment: I prepared a prime table and multiplied all the prime no first. The ans is 2305567963945518424753102147331756070 for all prime. Then tried to take lcm(primefactor, allOtherNo), but it is very complicted.

Comment: According to my code the answer should be 69720375229712477164533808935312303556800, which is equal to  2^6 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 7^2 * all primes from 11 to 97. I checked with other softwares. It should be correct.